# fwrite keeps failing not sure why

Tags: c, fwrite

In my code below, the file is being written correctly as far as I can tell. When I look in the file floats.dat I see this stream of binary `ÍÌL@33c@ÍÌÜ@ffFAßOeA^@^@bBf6zE33äCff<83>BÍÌ¦B`

However my program always ends up triggering this if statement:

```
if(fread(inputFloats, sizeof(float), LENGTH, binaryFile) < LENGTH)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Problem reading some or all data from %s\n\n", binaryFileName);
   return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Does anybody see something I've done wrong here? Full code below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define LENGTH 10

int main(void)
{
   FILE *binaryFile, *textFile;
   char *binaryFileName = "floats.dat", *textFileName = "floats.txt";
   float floats[LENGTH] = {3.2, 3.55, 6.9, 12.4, 14.332, 56.5, 4003.4, 456.4, 65.7, 83.4};
   float inputFloats[LENGTH];
   int i;

   if((binaryFile = fopen(binaryFileName, "r+")) == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Problem opening %s", binaryFileName);
   }

   if(fwrite(floats, sizeof(float), LENGTH, binaryFile) < LENGTH)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Problem writing some or all data to %s\n", binaryFileName);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   printf("DATA WRITTEN SUCCESSFULLY\n");

   if(fread(inputFloats, sizeof(float), LENGTH, binaryFile) < LENGTH)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Problem reading some or all data from %s\n\n", binaryFileName);
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }

   for(i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
   {
      printf("float[%d] = %f\n", i, floats[i]);
   }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Are there seperate file-positions for reading and writing on the same file? If not fread is trying to read floats behind those that you just wrote. In that case use `rewind(binaryFile)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You're not working with text data so you should specify a binary mode when opening the file. Use `r+b` instead of `r+`
- You need to `fseek(binaryFile, 0, SEEK_SET)` to "rewind" the file after writing. `rewind` can also be used for this case - `fseek` allows you to position the read/write pointer wherever you want.

Comment: That's perfect thanks Erik. Is there any downfall to using a simpler call such as what @steabert used below - rewind(binaryFile)?

Comment: Also I was just playing around, and now that it's working I still get the same result even when using 'r+'. Is specifying 'r+b' a fail safe for your code in the event that it is ported to a different system with perhaps a different implementation of fopen which doesn't accept using binary files when opened with 'r+'?

Comment: @Chris Paynter: `rewind` is perfectly fine here. You should know about `fseek` though. `r+b` ensures that noone fiddles with embedded `\n` - it may not be needed on your platform

Answer (score 1):

The `FILE` structure keeps a record of where in the file it is currently pointing. Since you've just written to `binaryFile`, the file pointer is at the *end* of what you've written.

You therefore need to rewind the file, using `fseek(binaryFile, 0, SEEK_SET);` before you read.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to rewind your file before reading it:

```
rewind(binaryFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you finish writing to the file, the FILE pointer is at the end of it, so of course if you try reading it will not work. Try using `fseek` to move the pointer to the beginning of the file before reading.

Please avoid this :

```
if((binaryFile = fopen(binaryFileName, "r+")) == NULL) {
```

and prefer this:

```
binaryFile = fopen(binaryFileName, "rb+");
if(!binaryFile) {
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with assignment in a condition when it's as clearly readable as it is here.

Comment: `=` in a conditional jump is never worth it. Better safe than sorry.